# When to use ALL in where and when not to use ALL in where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
    (SELECT MIN(period_start) as date
     FROM Sales 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 day)
     FROM CTE
     WHERE date <= ALL (SELECT MAX(period_end) FROM Sales))
```

What is the difference of using ALL in the where clause and not using ALL?

I have tried both, all returns the same result.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/all-subqueries.html#:~:text=The%20word%20ALL%20%2C%20which%20must,table%20t1%20containing%20(10)%20.

Comment: `value <operator> ALL (<subquery>)` evaluates to true when the value compared against each and every row the subquery produces evaluates to true.

Comment: Your query doesn't need `ALL` since the subquery produces a single row.

Comment: Do not use ALL/ANY/SOME at all - you may always create a condition which do the same but does not use these keywords.

Answer (score 1):

The `ALL` function means the comparison must be true for all values returned by the subquery. But the subquery returns only one value, because you used the aggregate function MAX() with no GROUP BY clause.

Using ALL in this specific example makes no difference. It does no harm, but it is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ANY` and `ALL` operators are used with `WHERE` or `HAVING`.
2. `ANY` and `ALL` operate on subqueries that return multiple values.
3. `ANY` returns true if any of the subquery values meet the condition.
4. `ALL` returns true if all of the subquery values meet the condition.

Example:

```
SELECT column-names
FROM table-name
WHERE column-name operator ALL 
      (SELECT column-name
       FROM table-name
       WHERE condition)
```